# GAE Python - get_by_key_name no result - maybe Parent issue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, parent, google-cloud-datastore

I use a simple Model.get_by_key_name('item_key') to retrieve an item from the datastore. This all worked fine until today, whereas now the query is returning None, although I can confirm that there is an existing entity with that key name.

As far as I know, the only thing I have changed to the model today, is adding a parent upon creation. I'm not very familiar with parent/ancestor. Could this influence the way I have to call the entity? What else can I try to figure out what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_key_name , the `get_by_key_name` function must be told about the parent, if any -- the parent alters the actual key used in the store.

Specifically, the signature is:

```
Model.get_by_key_name (key_names, parent=None)
```

(you can actually pass multiple key names as long as the entities have the same parent).  The default is `parent=None` which worked when you were getting entities **without** a parent -- but now that the parent is there, it must be specified in the call.

The key includes the kind of entity (here that's supplied by the specific subclass of `Model` you're calling the method on), the id or name, the parent, and the namespace (no need to worry about the last bit unless you're explicitly using namespaces:-).

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it :-).

Comment: @mgilson, funny how often SO turns into a speed race these days, hm?-)   Personally, as long as Qs on google-* tags are answered rapidly and well, I'm happy whoever's answering (pushing that is part of my current job in tech support for google cloud platform)...!

Comment: I find that trying to put in a good answer quickly helps to keep me sharp -- It helps with knowing where/how to look up relative information quickly and it helps to keep the more important basic stuff (`collections`, `itertools`) stored fresh in my in-memory cache :-).

Comment: @mgilson, yep, I find it easier for Python and its standard lib -- and the parts of 3rd party modules and GCP I know in depth; but there are so many 3rd party modules and GCP components that it's an ongoing challenge (as you say it keeps me sharp -- just like my daily Sudoku:-).